# iPhone 4 UITableView with UIImageView as hint

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios4

I have an app with UITableView and on selecting of row it displays the form with fields.

If user does not enter the whole data i am displaying a image on row of uitableview which indicates that row has incomplete data.

I can able to add uiimage to uitableview but i don't know who to display user that "image indicates Incomplete".

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound like a UX issue to discuss with your designer. you might want to use a label with descriptive text instead.